# LoopBack Remote Method to return array of records

Tags: loopback, angular-loopback

I used loopback to generate my api and AngularJS to communicate with it. I have a model called `Sync` that contains the following records:

```
Sync": {
"34": "{\"uuid\":\"287c6625-4a95-4e11-847e-ad13e98c75a2\",\"table\":\"Property\",\"action\":\"create\",\"timeChanged\":1466598611995,\"id\":34}",
"35": "{\"uuid\":\"287c6625-4a95-4e11-847e-ad13e98c75a2\",\"table\":\"Property\",\"action\":\"update\",\"timeChanged\":1466598625506,\"id\":35}",
"36": "{\"uuid\":\"176aa537-d000-496a-895c-315f608ce494\",\"table\":\"Property\",\"action\":\"update\",\"timeChanged\":1466598649119,\"id\":36}"
}
```

in my sync.js Model file I am trying to write the following method that accepts number (long - the timeChanged) and should return all of the records that are have equal or equal timeChanged field.

This is where I am at:

```
Sync.getRecodsAfterTimestamp = function(timestamp, cb){
var response = [];
Sync.find(
  function(list) {
    /* success */
  // DELETE ALL OF THE User Propery ratings associated with this property
  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].timeChanged == timestamp){
      response += list[i];
      console.log("Sync with id: " + list[i].id);
    }
  }
  cb(null, response);
},
function(errorResponse) { /* error */ });
}

Sync.remoteMethod (
'getRecodsAfterTimestamp',
{
  http: {path: '/getRecodsAfterTimestamp', verb: 'get'},
  accepts: {arg: 'timeChanged', type: 'number', http: { source: 'query' } },
  returns: {arg: 'name', type: 'Array'}
 }
);
```

When I try this method  in the loopback explorer I see this "AssertionError"

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem must be due to incorrect arguments supplied to the Sync.find() method. (You have provided 2 functions for success and error scenarios). As per the [Strongloop documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-find), the persisted model's find function has 2 arguments viz. an optional filter object and a callback. The callback uses the node error-first style.

Please try changing your Sync.find() to something like below:

```
Sync.find(function(err, list) {
if (err){
    //error callback
}
    /* success */
// DELETE ALL OF THE User Propery ratings associated with this property
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if(list[i].timeChanged == timestamp){
        response += list[i];
        console.log("Sync with id: " + list[i].id);
    }
}
cb(null, response);
});
```